# Java - read text file with specific jvm size

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, file-read

I have created a .txt test file containing only character 'a'. The file size is about 20 MB. I tried to read the file in three ways

Using BufferedReader

```
String fileName = "C:\\testFile.txt";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
```

Using Scanner

```
 Scanner sc = null;

    try {

        sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\testFile2.txt"), "UTF-8");
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        if (sc.ioException() != null) {
            throw sc.ioException();
        }
    } finally {

        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
```

And, using Java8 stream

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I set my jvm heap size using eclipse run configuration as shown here 
http://www.planetofbits.com/eclipse/increase-jvm-heap-size-in-eclipse/

In all three cases my value is : -Xms5M -Xmx100M.

Even though the file size is 20MB, it is always giving java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. When I set the heap size to -Xmx200M, it runs fine for all. I wonder what is eating up the memory and whether there is another more memory efficient way to read the file.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
*Profiling*

Thanks Rann and Adam. I did use Jprofiler for the Scanner code. 
The memory usage is shown in
[the char[] array takes a lot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR32g.jpg) and
[OverAll memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqIWk.jpg)

It is interesting to see that char[] array taking up this much. No idea why!

Side note: Now I have changed my test file to contain integer and newline, so each line contains a random integer. With that in place, I can read the file ( even size of 100MB) easily with Scanner, as it will only read one line at a time. Previously, there was only character 'a' in the file and no new line.

Comment: The fact that the file is 20MB does not mean that 100MB of JVM heap memory will be sufficient for handling the file. This depends on the used libraries and DSs in your code. You can profile your java application using tools as described here : http://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers

Comment: Note that there is also a difference between the file size of a file with numerical characters vs the size in memory of those values stored as `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

The best way (imo) to answer your question would be to inspect you application with a memory profiling tool such as [Java VisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). These applications will allow you to inspect how your program's memory is allocated and perhaps allow you to see where excessive memory is being used.